# How to change the label color of the textfield in Struts 2

Tags: css, jsp, templates, struts2

I am stuck in changing the font color of

```
<s:textfield name="name" key="user.name"/>
```

Here `user.name=User` comes from resource bundle. So in JSP HTML page, it displays `User Name` label and a textfield, but I want to change the font of `User Name` label.

Comment: Do you want to change the label color or font? your title and content says different reqs.

Comment: I want yo change the text color of User Name not for the Textfield

Comment: you can add css and use cssClass as an attribute.

Comment: I already tried like:<style type="text/css">
 .fontStyle {
  color: white;
  fontfont-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
 }
 .key {color:blue; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold}
 
</style>                                                 <s:textfield class="fontStyle" name="user.userName" size="20px"></s:textfield> . But this applies to the Textfiled's Text color not the label color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CSS attribute selector. Give your `<s:textfield>` an id and reference this id in CSS like that:

```
<style type="text/css">
  label[for="nameFieldId"] {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<s:textfield id="nameFieldId" name="name" key="user.name"/>
```

This will work because `xhtml` theme generates `<label>` for `<s:textfield>` tag with `for` attribute.

Comment: Thanx dear, This worked but for every label id I have to add a seperate style, or there is any common solution

Comment: If you want style for every label then just `label{color:red;}`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code

```
<s:label value="user.name" cssStyle="color: #ffffff;"/>
<s:textfield name="name" required="true"/>
```

if not work above code
Struts support Theme and template feature for more information refer below link
http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/working-with-struts-2-theme-template/ (Link have exmple for showing error message with color)
and do changes according to your requirement

Comment: This will mess up generated HTML if `xhtml` theme is used. @Shubhankar: Shouldn't be accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

1.First define your textfield like this:

```
<s:textfield  id="tf1"  size="150%" />
```

2.Then create a label tag pointing to your created textfield like this:

```
<s:label  for="tf1" style="font-family:Arial;color: #af2d2d" value="my textfield"/>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: This code is for using a label ,seperately linked to a texfield in struts2 , not within the textfield .

Answer (score -1):

Can you check `<s:testfield>` tag will support style attribute? If supports do like this

```
<s:testfield name=“name” key=“user.name” style="color:red;"/>
```

or else do like this

```
<span style="color:red;">
  <s:testfield name=“name” key=“user.name” style="color:red;"/>
</span>
```

in above line displays red color..if your want your custom color change red to your custom color

Comment: cssStyle attribute is there, but that is chaning the Text Filed text color, any help will do me a fever. Thanks

Comment: style is not suppoted